# Sum of the squares of a sequences converge, does the product?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If we know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n)^2$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(b_n)^2$ both converge can we say that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_nb_n)$ converges?

Comment: Also: [$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty b_n^2$ converge show $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n b_n$ converges absolutely](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1557206/42969), [Square series problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/231970/42969)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $|a_{n}b_{n}| < a_{n}^2 + b_{n}^2$.
Use the comparison test.

Comment: Better to say $2|a_n b_n|\leq a_n^2+b_n^2$. The inequality is not always strict and the absolute value rules out the chance that $\sum a_n b_n$ is negatively divergent.

Comment: Yes, I was about to edit that exactly now xD. Thanks :).

Answer (score 1):

$(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nb_n)^2\le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n^2\times \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n^2$.  It will also be true for $(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_nb_n|)^2$ as well.  It is the Schwartz inequality applied for the vector space $l_2$.